# Experience with/of success

Tags: prepositions

Someone gives a talk about how he has overcome failure after failure to reach where he is today: a successful entrepreneur.

To describe this talk, one writes:

> "The speaker shares his experience with success."

However, my understanding of "experience with" is that you would have to have a certain level of expertise in whatever comes after "with," or have spent enough time doing/being involved in that particular matter.

If we take a look at [this discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/181228/experience-in-vs-experience-with), Astralbee explains nicely the difference between "experience with" and "experience in.

The problem still stands nonetheless: I still cannot quite decide if in the sentence above we should go with "with" or "of."

One thing worthy of note is that "experience of success" has significantly more results than "experience with success" on Google.